# Why is my array not updating?

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to make a dungeon crawl game(Basically a 10x10 map), And When I create the map(board) and change an element it doesn't print when I update it. I don't see anything wrong with my code and I have nowhere else to turn :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ChadDung.h"
using namespace std;

int createBoard();
int updateBoard();
int clear();
char board[10][10];
int xp = 10;
int yp = 4;

int main() {

    createBoard();
    board[xp][yp] = 'G';
    clear();
    updateBoard();

}

int createBoard(){
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){

        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++){
            board[x][y] = '.';
            cout << board[x][y];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


int updateBoard(){
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){

        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++){
            cout << board[x][y];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


int clear(){
    cout << string( 25, '\n' );
}
```

There should be a 'G' on the bottom row but it just shows ".........."

Comment: index starts from 0. board[xp][yp] = 'G'; is not valid

Answer (score 5):

`char board[10][10];`

`xp = 10;`

`board[xp][yp] = 'G';`

When you set "G", you have run off the end of the array (valid indexes are 0-9), so you're getting undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks! Now i feel stupid because I remember learning this :P

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the 'G' in the wrong place in array. You are going out of limits. Your array varies from a[0][0] to a[9][9].

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I tried your code and got errors because your functions don't return a value (you declared them as returning an int) so change those to return void. Then, to answer your question, the reason you don't see a 'G' is because **your value for xp is 10, which is outside the range of the grid.** Remember, in code, in general, things are 0-based, so slots 1-10 are actually referred to as slots 0-9. So I changed sp = 10 to xp = 9 and your 'G' shows up like a charm.

---

```
#include <iostream>

void createBoard();
void updateBoard();
void clear();

using namespace std;

void createBoard();
void updateBoard();
void clear();
char board[10][10];
int xp = 9;
int yp = 4;

int main() {

    createBoard();
    board[xp][yp] = 'G';
    clear();
    updateBoard();

}

void createBoard() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){

        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++){
            board[x][y] = '.';
            cout << board[x][y];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


void updateBoard(){
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){

        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++){
            cout << board[x][y];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


void clear(){
    cout << string( 25, '\n' );
}
```